# how to list all files with matching permissions of another file

Tags: linux, files, permissions, find

I want to write a script that displays all files in a directory with the same permission as file a.txt. Basically if I have myFile.txt, with permission 777 and I say hey, how many other files do I have in this directory with that same permission status?

(From the comments: ACLs and ownership do not need to match)

Comment: man find and look at the -perm flag

Comment: Should ownership and ACLs if any match as well?

Comment: No just find if there is any files in the documents directory that has the same 777 permission as myFile.txt.  if so I can find and change them all to something like 775 or +× (make them all executable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one-liner

```
perms=$(stat -c %a a.txt); find /your/directory -type f -perm "$perms"
```